# Xquery to map the value of a specific name attribute

Tags: mapping, xquery, osb, name-value

I am trying to create an xquery in jdeveloper . I am stuck at a small portion of it. It would be great if I get some suggestions.
Below is the part I am stuck at

The request is:

```
`<variables>
  <variable name="StartTime" value="01:00:00"/>
 <variable name= "EndTime" value="05:00:00"/>
```

The response I want to map is a single element with two values looks like below:

```
<ns2:time ns2:startTime="01:00:00" ns2:endTime="05:00:00"/>
```

Below is the xquery I tried. But I get only the start time at both places. I want some way by which I can correctly assign the values looking at the name value in the request.

```
  if (fn:data($Prefereces/ns1:variables/ns1:variable/@name="StartTime")or fn:data($Prefereces/ns1:variables/ns1:variable/@name="EndTime")) then
                   ( <ns2:time ns2:startTime="{fn:data($Prefereces/ns1:variables/ns1:variable/@value)}" ns2:endTime="{fn:data($Prefereces/ns1:variables/ns1:variable/@value)}">
                    </ns2:time>)
                else
                    ()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
<ns2:time ns2:startTime="{fn:data($Prefereces/variables/variable[@name = 'StartTime']/@value)}" ns2:endTime="{fn:data($Prefereces/variables/variable[@name = 'EndTime']/@value)}"/>
```

Note that the `ns2` prefix has to be defined beforehand.

XQuery's predicates are specified using brackets (`[condition]`), which were missing from your tries.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that when the variables are missing, the attributes will be present with an empty value. If you want to avoid that, you could specify a list of attributes when you create the `ns2:time`, where you could specify each attribute only when you have their data.